# How would I add an Item to Minecraft with mcp-reborn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I am learning how to mod Minecraft, so I have very little experience with this yet (I have already made some resource packs). I am using [MCP Reborn](https://github.com/Hexeption/MCP-Reborn) but I'm open to better suggestions. I have already decompiled and have been messing around with this for a couple of months but to no avail. I have already created the textures for this item.
Could someone please help me with this? (Minecraft Java Edition 1.17.1)
(note: I do not want my mod to be dependent on other programs like forge.)

Comment: I know how to do this. I am just setting up an MCP environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this. This is not the only way. Make sure to replace all the placeholders (boring mod and boring item) with whatever you want.

Create a class something like this:

```
package me.mcblueparrot.mods.wow;

import net.minecraft.core.Registry;
import net.minecraft.resources.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;

public class BoringMod {

    public static final BoringMod INSTANCE = new BoringMod();
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "boringmod";

    public void bootstrap() {
        Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, locationOf("boringitem") /* boringmod:boringitem */, new Item(new Item.Properties()
                .tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_MATERIALS /* whatever tab you want */)));
    }

    private ResourceLocation locationOf(String path) {
        return new ResourceLocation(NAMESPACE, path);
    }

}
```

In net.minecraft.client.main.Main, add this:

```
BoringMod.INSTANCE.bootstrap();
```

after this (line 141)

```
CrashReport.preload();
Bootstrap.bootStrap();
```

In net.minecraft.client.resources.DefaultClientPackResources, change this:

```
super(p_174827_, "minecraft", "realms");
```

to

```
super(p_174827_, "minecraft", "realms", "boringmod");
```

Move your texture to "src/main/resources/assets/boringmod/textures/item/boringitem.png".

Create a new file in "src/main/resources/assets/boringmod/models/item/boringitem.json". The contents should look something like this:

```
{
  "parent": "minecraft:item/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "boringmod:item/boringitem"
  }
}
```

Create another file at "src/main/resources/assets/boringmod/lang/en_us.json":

```
{
  "item.boringmod.boringitem": "Boring Item"
}
```

Make sure to refresh the project if you are in Eclipse IDE.

When you start the game there should be a new item in the game (scroll down in the creative inventory).

Good luck modding! In future I would recommend a mod loader, or a patching system that makes updates and distribution easier.

[image: Item in action]

Comment: Where would I create the class?

Comment: In whatever package you wish to. I would recommend me.yourname.mymodname.

Comment: I am completely new to this so I don't know what a "package" is (sorry im such a newb)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE |||

Comment: but I can use intellij if it's easier

Comment: I'm actually @ school right now so I won't be able to test this out until I get home

Comment: That's fine. I need time to test this anyway. If you do not know what a package is, I could explain, but you should probably learn Java basics anyway. If you do not want to, you are limited to MCreator (or any alternatives) which limits you to Forge/Fabric.

Comment: I will research java packages, thanks.

Comment: I also know c++ so that might help

Comment: I am having trouble compiling with the examples you provided @MrParrot

Comment: What is the error? You need to change `package me.mcblueparrot.mods.wow;`
 to whatever your package is.

Comment: I was having trouble last night getting the client to compile. The error was in net.minecraft.main.Main, right at the new line I added. It was saying something like "symbol unrecognized -  class boringmod" (where boringmod is my mod's name) my package was @ me.boringmod where the folder structure was ~/src/main/java/me/boringmod.java . (line 1: package me.boringmod) I was wondering if this was an error on my part placing the files in the correct places, or if I just set up mcp wrong. plz help @MrParrot?

Comment: Packages contain classes. They are basically the equivalent of namespaces. If you have me/boringmod.java, the package is `me`, and the class is `boringmod`. Package names are typically named after your domain name, but reversed instead (e.g. `google.com` -> `com/google`). Since I don't own any domains, I usually use `me/myname`. After the reversed domain, you usually put the name of the program (e.g. `me/myname/myprogram`). After the package, you put the class name followed by ".java". At the beginning of the class, you put `package package.path.here;`.

Comment: should I put my class into ~/src/main/java/me/boringmod/boringmod.java?

Comment: If you want to call your mod "boring mod" (or even better, BoringMod.java since that uses the standard naming conventions), yes.

Comment: still 1 error.  If I Put this in main like you said to (boringmod.INSTANCE.bootstrap();) where boringmod is replaced with my mod's name
C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCP-Reborn-1.18\src\main\java\net\minecraft\client\main\Main.java:141: error: package boringmod does not exist
      boringmod.INSTANCE.bootstrap();

Comment: and if I put in the package (me.boringmod.INSTANCE.bootstrap();)
this error occurs:
C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCP-Reborn-1.18\src\main\java\net\minecraft\client\main\Main.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
      me.boringmod.INSTANCE.bootstrap();
                  ^
  symbol:   class INSTANCE
  location: package me.boringmod

Comment: I re-structured the package like advised. I have no idea how to proceed. Please help me @MrParrot or make a screen recording of how you successfully compiled?

Comment: I could explain, but I'm not a teacher, and I think it would be better for you to try and research the basics of programming in Java.

Comment: I figured it out! now I was just wondering how to add a block...

Comment: You can adapt quite a lot of stuff from the Fabric wiki. For example, for blocks, this works pretty much the same: https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:blocks. Not all of them work, so if you want to make your life a bit easier, you could just use the Fabric mod loader, as it is very lightweight compared to Forge.

Comment: if you're on gamedev plz nswer my question there :https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/198972/how-would-i-add-a-new-custom-ore-to-the-nether-in-minecraft @MrParrot

Answer (score -1):

Given you are open to other suggestions I would recommend [MCreator](https://mcreator.net/). It is very simple to get going and integrates well into the game itself and makes the workflow very simple.

Comment: I will look into this, but I still want to know how to do this with the hard-coding method, just in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: I do not want to create mods depending on forge. I would like to make my own free-standing mod.

Comment: I downvoted this, as it doesn't answer the question. This would fit better as a comment. I wouldn't recommend MCreator, as you learn skills that will be applicable outside of Minecraft if you code a mod in Java. Despite this, MCreator is surprisingly capable, and there have been many high quality mods made with it.

Comment: I most definitely agree, as I like to get my hands dirty hard-coding things.

Comment: An edit was made to the question ("not depending on other things") after I posted this answer. My answer was relevant before that.

Comment: ok, I realize that now.. I guess I should have made my question more clear in the first place.